# On duplicate key update VS single query multiple updates

Tags: mysql

I have tried to find an answer to the question "which of the 2 options would be better in terms of performance?".

I have seen this post: [update-vs-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204289/update-vs-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update)

The thing is my testing shows me complete dominance for `insert .. update` over multiple updates.

This is the test i have done:

Transaction 1:

```
INSERT INTO indicators.filesi (sha256, VTAVAmount) VALUES
(0x000028670DB2A67449EFEAA1A6E96AFE1124094BB6123144780C9ECA19767B61, 2),
(0x000CA483837264B943BCD86A6C5F3A62F515690FD4D77863D4C690D783127EC5, 2),
... 10k rows
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VTAVAmount = VALUES(VTAVAmount)
```

Transaction 2:

```
update indicators.filesi set VTAVAmount= 2 where sha256 = 0x000028670DB2A67449EFEAA1A6E96AFE1124094BB6123144780C9ECA19767B61;
update indicators.filesi set VTAVAmount= 2 where sha256 = 0x000CA483837264B943BCD86A6C5F3A62F515690FD4D77863D4C690D783127EC5;
... 10k rows
```

`sha256` is indexed.

I have tried this numerous times, one in particular both transaction didn't update or insert anything, and the `insert ignore` is simply much much faster.

So am i missing something or is that true?

Using 10.2.15-MariaDB with 5.7.22 innoDb

Comment: 1) These query packs are not generally identical so the experiment makes no sense. 2) `INSERT IGNORE .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` makes no sence. Either ignore or update, not both.

Comment: @Akina 1) yes they are identical, don't understand your claim. 2) same same without ignore

Comment: *yes they are identical* NO. First may insert (if not dup), second cannot.

Comment: How large is the table?  Is the entire table cached in the buffer_pool?  How big is the buffer_pool?  I am checking to see if I/O (versus caching) is the difference in performance.

Comment: You say "transaction".  Do you mean that there is a `BEGIN` before the statement(s) and a `COMMIT` afterward?

Comment: @Rick James i tested on a rather small table, no IO. and yes - Begin and commit

Answer (score 3):

**Not quite the same, but related...**

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ... (one row);
INSERT ... (one row);
INSERT ... (one row);
COMMIT;
```

versus batching

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ... (one row),(one row),(one row);
COMMIT;
```

The batch `INSERT` (latter case) runs much faster than the former.  I have seen this in many situations.  I have repeatedly observed a factor of 10 is speed (when there are a lot of rows, not just 3).

You can think of it this way:  There are 10 units of work involved in receiving the query, parsing it, optimizing it, etc, etc, compared to 1 unit of work to insert a row.

So, I recommend batching `INSERTs` in groups of 100-1000.  More than that gets into diminishing returns.  That is, you get about 10x for any large batch size.

Back to the OP's question...  It seems very likely that a bunch of one-row `UPDATEs` would also take 10 times as long as a contorted IODKU that performs a similar task.

It is tricky to get **valid timing tests** for those two formulations.  The cache (buffer_pool) is a big factor in performance (a separate 10x).  If your table is bigger than the buffer pool, then it will be thrashing; if it is smaller, then be sure the either entirely cached or not at all cached.  Otherwise (again), I/O muddies the timings.

**Another formulation** to experiment with is

```
update indicators.filesi
    set VTAVAmount= 2 where sha256 IN (.., .., ...10K values...)
```

(and it might defuse the 'discussion' with Akina)

**Caching**. There is another issue with the task...  Sha256 (or md5 or uuid or ...) is especially bad for performance when the table (or at least the index) is bigger than the buffer_pool.  As the table gets bigger, the cache becomes less useful.  Beware.

It seems that you **sorted** the sha256s before building your queries.  This is good for performance, in that it helps avoid the thrashing.

On the other hand, when an `UPDATE` needs to **change 10K rows all at once**, the schema design comes into question.  Can the tables be redesigned to put `VTAVAmount` in some place so a single-row `UPDATE` takes care of the entire task?  (Sure, there would need to be a `JOIN` somewhere, but that is probably less hassle than a 10K-row update.)

Comment: 1. `set VTAVAmount= 2 where sha256 IN (.., .., ...10K values...)` is not an option since VTAmmount doesnt have to be the same for each row, so there is no single query update. 2. how many updates would you consider good for a batch?(500 batch, 1k?) 3.so in what scenario would you think IODKU would be faster that multiple update queries and when the other way arround?

Comment: @omri - I would batch only 100 at a time.  Fewer statements should be faster.

Comment: @omri - (In case my previous comment seems contradictory...)  Pick the method that launches the fewest number of SQL commands (IODKU/UPDATE/...); but then limit the number of rows to change in any given statement to about 100 rows (there by adding slightly to the number of commands.

Comment: I will do batches of 100 thats understood. Still what matters to me in this post is the question which of the 2 options(IODKU or Update)? so if you say " Pick the method that launches the fewest number of SQL commands",so that mean IODKU is the faster option? since its a single command